# Word VSTO Revision Interface

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-word, vsto

I am making a custom revision tab in the MS Word ribbon using C# in Visual Studio. While trying to figure out how to accept a revision in Word, I came across this [reference document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.revision?view=word-pia#methods).

Using this document, I've come up with the following code to try and test out some of the features of the revision interface:

```
int i = 0;

Object Rev = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Revisions(i);    // Get the first revision object

Object Rng = Rev.Range;                                     // Get the Range object of the first revision

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Revisions.Accept(i);          // Accept the first revision
```

I get an error on the second line [(Code Error ln2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSyNS.png) which says Revisions cannot be used as a method, and an error on the fourth line [Code Error ln4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsvX6.png) which says Revisions has no definition for Accept, but from what I read in the reference document, this should be the proper syntax. [Namespace Syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7epE6.png) , [Revisions Syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFng8.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The reference is probably in VB-speak. You're using C# so you have to address arrays/collections using square brackets rather the parentheses: Revisions[i];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the Syntax:

```
Word.Revision ThisRevision = Globals.ThisDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.NextRevision();    // Get Next Revision

Word.Range RevRange = ThisRevision.Range;    // Get Range of Revision

ThisRevision.Accept();    // Accept Revision
```